# Unknown column in where clause - Columna desconocida - MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Al intentar eliminar un registro sale el siguiente error:

> Unknown column 'RegistroNuevo' in 'where clause

Pero no es una columna, es el nombre del registro.

Código:

```
public bool EliminarPais(clsPaises paises)
    {
        MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection();

        try
        {
            cn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; database=world; user=root; pwd=root";
            cn.Open();

            string strSQL = "delete  from country where code = " + paises.Code;
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, cn);
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            comando.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
            cn.Dispose();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hola, por favor indica en la pregunta el código de la clase `clsPaises`, la estructura de la Tabla **country**.

Comment: Esta página no me deja editar la pregunta :(

Answer (score 0):

El valor de  `paises.Code` debes ponerlo entre comillas

Actualmente estás generando este SQL

```
delete  from country where code = RegistroNuevo
```

Como "**RegistroNuevo**" no está entre comillas, SQL lo interpreta como un campo y no como una cadena de texto, para que SQL lo trate como una cadena de texto, ponlo entre comillas.

```
 delete  from country where code = 'RegistroNuevo'
```

**Lo que tienes**

```
string strSQL = "delete  from country where code = " + paises.Code;
```

**Lo que deberías**

```
string strSQL = "delete  from country where code = '" + paises.Code + "'";
```

Te recomiendo leer sobre **Inyección SQL**.

Comment: Se deberia de poner entre comillas si el Where code fuera un string, si es el indice al ser tipo int no hace falta ponerlo entre comillas. Todo depende de la estructura de la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

El error "Unknown column 'RegistroNuevo' in 'where clause" se produce porque estás concatenando directamente el valor de paises.Code en tu consulta SQL sin usar comillas. Esto hace que MySQL interprete RegistroNuevo como una columna en lugar de un valor.

Para solucionar esto, debes encerrar el valor de paises.Code entre comillas en tu consulta SQL. Aquí tienes una versión modificada de tu código para corregir el problema:

```
public bool EliminarPais(clsPaises paises)
{
    MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection();

    try
    {
        cn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; database=world; user=root; pwd=root";
        cn.Open();

        string strSQL = "delete from country where code = '" + paises.Code + "'";
        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, cn);
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        comando.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.Close();
        cn.Dispose();
    }
    return true;
}
```

En esta versión modificada, hemos agregado comillas simples alrededor de paises.Code en la consulta SQL: where code = '" + paises.Code + "'". Esto asegura que MySQL trate paises.Code` como un valor de cadena en lugar de una columna.

Sin embargo, es importante tener en cuenta que concatenar valores directamente en una consulta SQL puede llevar a problemas de seguridad como la inyección SQL. Sería recomendable utilizar parámetros en su lugar para evitar posibles ataques y problemas de formato.

Comment: Copión de chatGPT. Vergüenza