# Mysql variable dentro de CONCAT()

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedure, mysql-workbench, concat

Trabajo con mysql-worbench

Pues tras un largo dia en el que he probado cientos de combinaciones (no es broma)
No he sido capaz de que en el concat me coja la variable "VarIP" como valida.

Edito para añadir el procedure:
***********Invoco con este procedure por si sirve:********

```
CALL pruebaconcat('Delete', 'usuario','192.168.1.10', '1')
```

---

Vuelvo a editar para afinar mas el problema, siento las molestias.
[Unknown column in where clause - Columna desconocida - MySql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/298845/unknown-column-in-where-clause-columna-desconocida-mysql)
En esa URL se soluciona el problema que tengo yo aqui, pero lo que no entiendo es por que esa solución no se aplica a mi caso, dando el error descrito aquí abajo UNKNOW COLUMN.

Y copiando el ejemplo tal cual obtengo el segundo error, el de sintaxis.

*********En este caso da unknow colum VarIP*************

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pruebaconcat`(IN VarAccion Varchar(20), 
IN VarUsuario varchar(20) ,IN VarIP varchar(30), IN VarVlan Int)
BEGIN
    SET @s = CONCAT("insert into `log_ip_ipv4`
(`IP` ,`Vlan`,`Ubicacion`,`Mac`,`DNS`,`Descripcion`,`Hostname_revisado`,`Hostname`,`tarea`,`usuario`)
select `IP`, `Vlan`, `Ubicacion`,`Mac`,`DNS`,
`Descripcion`,`Hostname_revisado`,`Hostname`,
`tarea`,`usuario`
from `1` where IP = "'+VarIP'";");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

**********En este error de sintaxis***************

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pruebaconcat`(IN VarAccion Varchar(20), 
IN VarUsuario varchar(20) ,IN VarIP varchar(30), IN VarVlan Int)
BEGIN
    SET @s = CONCAT("insert into `log_ip_ipv4`
(`IP` ,`Vlan`,`Ubicacion`,`Mac`,`DNS`,`Descripcion`,`Hostname_revisado`,`Hostname`,`tarea`,`usuario`)
select `IP`, `Vlan`, `Ubicacion`,`Mac`,`DNS`,
`Descripcion`,`Hostname_revisado`,`Hostname`,
`tarea`,`usuario`
from `1` where IP = "+VarIP);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

y en los otros cientos/miles de posibles combinaciones  que he probado da infinadad de errores, el caso es que no consigo que reconozca la sentencia del where como un condicional, si lo hago introduciendo el condicional de forma estática no hay problema en la ejecucion.
Pero necesito que se haga el trabajo por medio de esa variable, ya que contiene la IP de la fila que quiero borrar.

Un saludo a todos! Estoy desesperado con esto...

Comment: Ok, creo que en tu primer caso con que quites las "" de VarIP funciona, algo así:

CONCAT("insert into `log_ip_ipv4`
(`IP` ,`Vlan`,`Ubicacion`,`Mac`,`DNS`,`Descripcion`,`Hostname_revisado`,`Hostname`,`tarea`,`usuario`)
select `IP`, `Vlan`, `Ubicacion`,`Mac`,`DNS`,
`Descripcion`,`Hostname_revisado`,`Hostname`,
`tarea`,`usuario`
from `1` where IP = 'VarIP';");

Comment: No, haciendo lo que dices (lo hice en varias de los cientos de combinaciones (pero aun asi he vuelto a probar))
Lo unico que hace es no tirar ningun error, pero no hace nada .
Sin embargo si meto la ip a mano si, entiendo que no la está viendo como la variable que es.
Muchas Gracias pero no funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba de esta forma:

```sql
SET @s = CONCAT("insert into log_ip_ipv4
(IP ,Vlan,Ubicacion,Mac,DNS,Descripcion,Hostname_revisado,Hostname,tarea,usuario)
select IP, Vlan, Ubicacion,Mac,DNS,
Descripcion,Hostname_revisado,Hostname,
tarea,usuario
from 1 where IP = '", VarIP,"'");
```

**Ejemplo de Prueba**

Crear el procedimiento

```sql
delimiter //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pruebaconcat(IN VarIP Varchar(20), OUT cadena Varchar(400))
BEGIN
    SET cadena = CONCAT("insert into log_ip_ipv4
(IP ,Vlan,Ubicacion,Mac,DNS,Descripcion,Hostname_revisado,Hostname,tarea,usuario)
select IP, Vlan, Ubicacion,Mac,DNS,
Descripcion,Hostname_revisado,Hostname,
tarea,usuario
from 1 where IP = '", VarIP,"'");
END;//
```

Ejecutar el procedimiento

```sql
call pruebaconcat("127.0.0.1", @cad);
select @cad;
```

Comment: No, lo siento pero tampoco sirve, lo he probado tal cual lo has puesto.
Tambien con 20 formas mas con `comillas`sin comillas etc.
Gracias por ayudarme, pero tampoco me ha servido... la verdad es que esto se está convirtiendo en una quimera.

Comment: Realize unas pruebas y me funcione te coloco el ejemplo completo en la respuesta

Comment: No, a ver, tu ejemplo funciona, pero no es lo que pregunto, el tema es, que cuando consigo que reconozca la variable como tal, el where no lo reconoce como condicional y busca la columna en lugar del campo dando el error:
Uknow column.

Tu ejemplo funciona por que no tiene que comparar la variable VarIP con el dato de la columna IP.

Es decir where IP = VarIP --- uknow column

De verdad muchas gracias por el tiempo que me estás dedicando, te lo agradezco enormemente, pero no me ha servido.

un saludo!

Comment: en este caso es varchar, pero si meto la ip a mano en lugar de por variable 192.168.1.1 no da ningún problema, solo lo da cuando lo hago por variable.
Edito un momento el problema principal, para explicarlo mejor.
Siento las molestias de verdad.

Comment: voy a modificar la respuesta porque si es un varchar deberia ir asi `IP = '", VarIP,"'");`

Comment: Joder Muchisimas pero Muchisimas gracias, menudo fallo de novato.
Eran las comas......
Acabo de probarlo y ha tirado a fondo.

Comment: de nada a todos nos ha pasado alguna vez